# jsonpath for logical AND

Tags: jsonpath

I need a Jsonpath for checking a the credentials from a input.json like below.

```json
{
  "Attributes": {
    "Attribute": [
      {
        "name": "uid",
        "value": "account1"
      },
      {
        "name": "pwd",
        "value": "secret"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Each of the following conditions works separately. But I could not find a way to logically AND them together.

```
$.Attributes.Attribute[?(@.name == 'uid' && @.value == 'account1')]
$.Attributes.Attribute[?(@.name == 'pwd' && @.value == 'secret')]
```

Like

```
$.Attributes.Attribute[?(@.name == 'uid' && @.value == 'account1')] && $.Attributes.Attribute[?(@.name == 'pwd' && @.value == 'secret')]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this with JSON Path, you need to iterate one level higher to find child arrays that contain both objects by using a nested filter query.

```
$.Attributes[?@[?@.name == 'uid' && @.value == 'account1'] && @[?@.name == 'pwd' && @.value == 'secret']]
```

Here's the breakdown:

```
$
 .Attributes                    // enter object
    [?                          // iterate and find a value that
      @[?                       // has a child that
         @.name == 'uid' &&     // matches condition 1
         @.value == 'account1'
       ]
      &&                        // and
      @[?                       // has a child that
         @.name == 'pwd' &&     // matches condition 2
         @.value == 'secret'
       ]
    ]
```

It works by finding *any* element of `Attributes` that contains both of the items you're looking for.  So if `Attributes` had other children, it would look at those, too.

```json
{
  "Attributes": {
    "Attribute1": [
      {
        "name": "uid",
        "value": "account1"
      },
      {
        "name": "pwd",
        "value": "secret"
      }
    ],
    "Attribute2": [
      {
        "name": "uid",
        "value": "account2"
      },
      {
        "name": "pwd",
        "value": "secret"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For this, it only returns the first one (under `Attribute1`).

```json
{
  "Attributes": {
    "Attribute": [
      {
        "name": "uid",
        "value": "account1"
      },
      {
        "name": "pwd",
        "value": "secret"
      }
    ],
    "Attribute2": [
      {
        "name": "uid",
        "value": "account1"
      },
      {
        "name": "pwd",
        "value": "secret"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For this, it would return both.

---

This only works because the array is nested under another structured value (array/object).  If the array was at the root, e.g.

```json
[
  {
    "name": "uid",
    "value": "account1"
  },
  {
    "name": "pwd",
    "value": "secret"
  }
]
```

then you couldn't do what you want.  You have to have the nested iterations to make this work.

---

You can test this out on [my playground](https://json-everything.net/json-path), which runs .Net WASM.